# Successfully managed to open up WhatsApp chatbox of specified number programatically. How to send a message to the same chat programatically?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to open a WhatsApp chatbox of a specified number programatically, and send a message (also, desired to be done programatically.) Si far, I've only been successful in opening up the chatbox, but not sending a message. Here's the code I'm using to do so.

```
void openWhatsappContact(String number, Context context) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + number);
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
        i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "test");
        Intent mStart = Intent.createChooser(i, "");
        mStart.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(mStart);
    }
```

Is there a way I can send a WhatsApp message to the opened chatbox programatically?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
void openWhatsappContact(String number, Context context) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + number);
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, mUri);
        mIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        mIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "The text goes here");
        mIntent.putExtra("chat",true);
        context.startActivity(mIntent);
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but what's "sms_body"?

Comment: What? How is it different from the message? Could you please elaborate a little.